# MariaDB/MySQL: улучшение SQL-запроса

Tags: mysql, sql

В оптимизации одного из подзапросов я дошел до такого состояния:

```
    SELECT foo.id
      FROM foo
INNER JOIN bar AS f ON foo.id = bar.foo_id
  GROUP BY foo.id
    HAVING MAX(foo.baz) != MAX(bar.baz)
```

Важно здесь следующее:

- используется MariaDB
- таблицы *foo* и *bar* связаны отношением один-ко-многим
- подзапросы запрещены
- возвращается одно поле - foo.id

**Не нравится хак с агрегатной функцией в HAVING** — если применительно к полю bar.baz оно имеет смысл (выбираем только те записи, для которых поле foo.baz не равно максимальному bar.baz), то в случае с полем foo.baz оно используется исключительно для того, чтобы убрать поле из блока SELECT. Плюс, есть риск того, что max(*) возвращает не ожидаемый результат.

Как улучшить запрос?

Comment: Почему нельзя использовать подзапросы? Это относится к временным таблицам? И на сколько большие таблицы, тоже хотелось бы знать.

Comment: 1. Ограничения, наложенные бизнесом и стремлением снять нагрузку с БД по возможности. 2. Таблицы на несколько миллионов записей каждая.

Comment: было бы не плохо написать, что ожидается от запроса и структуру 2 таблиц.

Answer (score 0):

Мне казалось что бизнесу главное что бы было правильно и быстро.
Можно попробовать такой вариант с временной таблицей, должно быть быстрее.

```
select bar.foo_id, MAX(bar.baz) baz
into #bar
from bar
group by bar.foo_id

create index ix on #bar (foo_id, baz)

select foo.id
from foo
join #bar bar on foo.id = bar.foo_id AND foo.baz <> bar.baz
```

Comment: Не пойдет. Запрос сам по себе простой и используется в качестве операнда в более крупном запросе. Поэтому это должен быть а) простой запрос, б) один запрос.

Comment: А количество уникальных id в таблицах одинаково? Может быть что в одной есть такие id, которых нет в другой?

Comment: Повторюсь: связь один-ко-многим. Потенциально, может запись в foo, которой нет в bar, но не может быть записей в bar, которых нет в foo.

Comment: Поломал голову, решения со всеми условиями которые описаны я не нашел. С внутренним запросом очень красиво получается, попробуйте рассмотреть вариант его использования. Даже с учетом что он будет использовать в другом большом запросе. Помнится был запрос в 2 тысячи строк, подзапросы опускались на 15 уровней, и все работало довольно быстро. К слову, во временную таблицу никто не запрещает всунуть данные до выполнения "большого" запроса.

Comment: Собственно в том и вопрос — есть ли возможность еще улучшить запрос. Безусловно, есть варианты и с подзапросами. Другое дело что из-за существующей нагрузки на БД использовать их не рекомендуется